# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: .net-7.0

I've been getting this error message when I try to run my Azure function v4.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot
> find the file specified.

After upgrading the Azure function from `.net6.0` to `.net7.0` I get the above error.

These are the package references in my function project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>96d7c15a-e5e1-411c-a64e-d5f4d9e15b78</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="enum\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="enum\**" />
    <None Remove="enum\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.8.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Common" Version="12.13.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.7.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.17.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="3.2.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.5" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="5.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" Version="1.0.8" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="4.0.1" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="3.1.13" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Has anyone else got it or any idea on how to resolve it?

I can see the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll` (v7) in the debug folder as well. Not sure why the runtime complains about it.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Update the package in your Package manager console `Update-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions
`